# Deleting MongoDB documents on non indexed field

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongoDB database of 80 million rows. Every document has 15-17 fields. Only 3 of them are indexed.

I have to delete a few million documents based on a non indexed field.

Mongo became so slow that I cannot even get the count of documents matching my query. Is there any way to make this delete faster (If its possible)?

Is creation of the index now feasible?

Answer (score 0):

Creating an index will be fine, you can even stop it blocking other database operations by settings the `background:true` flag in the options:

```
db.collection.createIndex({a:1}, {background:true})
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#options-for-all-index-types

Comment: Creation of index worked. But even now a find operation on it is taking forever

Comment: Do an explain on the query